# how to pass just the function from one component to other component without passing the whole component or button click

Tags: reactjs

I am new to react and in a bit of a problem . I have a component, component1. which has a function.

```
class ReportModal extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      modal: false,
      imagesList: [],
      code: []
    };

    this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
  }

  toggle() {
    this.setState({
      modal: !this.state.modal
    });
  }

render() {
return(
<component1/>
)
}
```

I want to pass the toggle function in another component, component2

```
class Report extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          modal: false
          
        };
    
        
      }
    
      
    render() {
    return(
    <component2/>
    )
    }
```

How do I pass just the toggle function from one component to another without passing the whole component or using a click event

Comment: Check the docs for Context API https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#api

Comment: I am not just trying to toggle the theme that is an example function what I require is to get a function from 1 component to other just the function

Answer (score 0):

You will have to firstly set the hierarchy of your components such as parent, sibling or child component. You can pass information from parent to child component through props.

Reverse flow occurs as a callback function.
If you want to call a function from parent component, create a function inside it and pass function as props.

```
 class ReportModal extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = {
     modal: false,
     imagesList: [],
     code: []
   };

  this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
 }

toggle(modal) {
   this.setState({
    modal: modal
   });
  }

 render() {
     return(
      <component2 mod={this.toggle}/>
        )
      }
```

The child component will call this function on the occurrence of event and provide child data.

```
  class Component2 extends React.Component {
           constructor(props) {
           super(props);
          this.handleClick=this.handleClick.bind(this);
        }

    handleClick(){
       this.props.mod(true)
      }
       

   render(){
       return (
             <button onClick={this.handleClick}></button>
         )}
        }
```

Comment: can we do this without using the onclick event

Comment: can you show how we can pass from a child to parent component

Comment: I already mentioned that. You have passed the function from parent to child as props(this.toggle)And now the child component is calling the props which is function toggle and when you call a function you invoke it (toggle()) and pass argument to it which is toggle(true). The argument is the same argument of parent function that is used to change setstate of modal.

Comment: check this doc for more clarity -  https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html